# Device: force orientation landscape (Phonegap JQueryMobile)

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova, screen-orientation

I have been searching for days for a way to always display just one particular jquery mobile page div in landscape mode.

Anyone any examples or ideas that could help, I would really appreciate it.

```
function forceLandscape() {
    console.log('Starting: forceLandscape ');
    console.log('----------------------------------------------------');


    //    var orientation = window.orientation;
    //    var new_orientation = 0;
    //    switch (orientation) {
    //        case 90:
    //            break;
    //        case -90:
    //            new_orientation = 180
    //            $('body').css({ ".ui-mobile,.ui-mobile .ui-page{min-height:300px} -webkit-transform": "rotate(" + new_orientation + "deg);" });
    //            break;
    //        case 180:
    //            new_orientation = 270;
    //            $('body').css({ ".ui-mobile,.ui-mobile .ui-page{min-height:300px} -webkit-transform": "rotate(" + new_orientation + "deg);" });
    //            break;
    //        case 0:
    //            new_orientation = 90;
    //            $('body').css({ ".ui-mobile,.ui-mobile .ui-page{min-height:300px} -webkit-transform": "rotate(" + new_orientation + "deg);" });
    //            break;
    //        default:
    //            $('body').css({ ".ui-mobile,.ui-mobile .ui-page{min-height:300px} -webkit-transform": "rotate(" + new_orientation + "deg);" });
    //    }  


    console.log('----------------------------------------------------');
    console.log('Completed: forceLandscape ');
}
```

Comment: A page with jquery mobile page having landscape orientation?

Comment: `<div data-role="page" id="landscape" data-theme="a" data-content-theme="a" data-add-back-btn="true">` I want this div to always be in landscape even if phone is in portal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't recommended but you could do:

```
$('body').css({
   "-webkit-transform": "rotate(90deg)"
   put other browsers here
});
```

or just in css

```
#page {
transform:rotate(90deg);
-ms-transform:rotate(90deg); /* IE 9 */
-moz-transform:rotate(90deg); /* Firefox */
-webkit-transform:rotate(90deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
-o-transform:rotate(90deg); /* Opera */
}
```

Comment: I had some thing like this prev i was getting weird results

Comment: what do you mean by weird can you elaborate?

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me, The Page was rotating but its height and width were incorrect. the page kept its original width and was centred with white borders on both sides.

Comment: codaniel have you any examples of your css working, i am also using the 960 grid format jquery mobile [link](http://jeromeetienne.github.com/jquery-mobile-960/) and i think this might be causing the issue.

Comment: @lmac34 You have to add an event listener and then change stuff based on `window.height` and `window.width`.