# Force Phonegap V3.4 ( jQuery Mobile application) to landscape view without rotating device

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am looking for a way to force the device to change to landscape view in some of pages without rotating device in Phonegap 3.4.

I searched online and saw some plugins but they are not supporting new version of Phonegap.

I also read  this:https://stackoverflow.com/a/9837806/765498.

But, is there a plugin that I can use instead of manipulating CSS?